# The maximum possible area bounded by the parabola $y = x^2 + x + 10$ and a chord of the parabola of length $1$ is?

Tags: conic-sections, area

The maximum possible area bounded by the parabola $y = x^2 + x + 10$ and a chord of the parabola of length $1$ is?

$(y-39/4)=(x+1/2)^2$, Vertex: $(-1/2, 3/4)$

How do I find the equation of the chord whose length is $1$?

Comment: Did you mean vertex $(-1/2, 39/4)$?

Comment: Note a chord is line segment with each end point on the parabola, so these end points, call them $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, must have $y_i = x_i^2 + x_i + 10$ for $i=1,2$. For the chord length to be $1$ requires that $\sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2} = 1 \implies (x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the equation of the secant line be $y=mx+b$. Combining this with the equation of the parabola produces the quadratic equation $$x^2+(1-m)x+(10-b)=0.$$ To reduce clutter, I’ll denote the discriminant of this equation by $\Delta = (1-m)^2-4(10-b)$. The solutions to this equation are, of course, $$x = \frac12(m-1)\pm\frac12\sqrt\Delta$$ and substituting this into the parabola’s equation results in $$y=\frac14(m^2+\Delta+39)\pm\frac12m\sqrt\Delta.$$ The square of the length of the corresponding chord is therefore simply $(1+m^2)\Delta$. Setting this equal to $1$ and solving for $b$ yields $$b=10-\frac14(1-m)^2+{1 \over 4(1+m^2)},$$ so you now have the equations of a family of secants with chord length equal to $1$ parameterized by slope, but you really only need $\Delta$ and $b$ to solve the problem.

There’s a property of parabolas that’s handy for attacking this problem: The area bounded by a parabola and its chord is equal to two-thirds of the area of the bounding paralellogram (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Facts_related_to_chords) for details). The problem thus becomes one of finding the value of the slope $m$ that maximizes the area of this paralellogram, which is a lot easier to compute. In fact, since the chord length is fixed at $1$, the problem reduces even further to finding the value of $m$ for which the distance between the chord and the tangent parallel to it is maximized. By symmetry, that’s likely to occur when the tangent is at the vertex, i.e., when $m=0$.

Either by differentiating or by using the fact that midpoints of parallel chords lie on a line parallel to the parabola’s axis, you can find that the tangent to the parabola has a slope of $m$ when $x=\frac12(m-1)$. Substituting the value of $b$ computed above into the expression for $\Delta$ simplifies it to $\Delta = \frac1{1+m^2}$. The distance between the secant and this tangent is equal to the difference between the $y$-coordinates of the midpoint of the chord and the point of tangency†, divided by the normalizing factor of $\sqrt{1+m^2}$, which simplifies to $$\frac\Delta{4\sqrt{1+m^2}} = \frac1{4(1+m^2)^{3/2}}.$$ Therefore, the area of the parabolic segment is $\frac1{6(1+m^2)^{3/2}}$, which obviously has its maximum at $m=0$, as suspected.

---

† Alternatively, find the $y$-intercept of the tangent by solving $\Delta=0$ for $b$, and subtract this from the value of $b$ computed above for the secant.

Answer (score 2):

Such a chord would intersection the parabola at points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, where $\sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2} = 1$. Notice that if you square this expression, you get $(y_2 - y_1)^{2} = 1 - (x_2 - x_1)^2$. Here, you'd have $y_2 = x^{2}_{2} + x_2 + 10$ and $y_1 = x^{2}_{1} + x_1 + 10$.

Comment: If you square $\sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2} = 1$, you get $(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 = 1$. However, in general, and also in this case, I don't see how you can then get $y_2 - y_1 = -(x_2 - x_1)$. If this were true, then you'd get $|y_2 - y_1| = |x_2 - x_1| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: I didn't notice that mistake. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I consider the
more general parabola

$y(x) 
= x^2 + ax + b
$
with the points being
$(x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^2
$.

I am close to a solution,
but am pooping out
so am leaving my answer incomplete.

One surprising result
I find is that
the area between the
chord and the parabola is
$\dfrac{(x_2-x_1)^3}{6}
$.

The length of the chord is

$\begin{array}\\
L^2
&=(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2\\
&=(x_2-x_1)^2+((x_2^2 + ax_2 + b)-(x_1^2 + ax_1 + b))^2\\
&=(x_2-x_1)^2+(x_2^2-x_1^2 + a(x_2-x_1))^2\\
&=(x_2-x_1)^2+((x_2-x_1)(x_2+x_1) + a(x_2-x_1))^2\\
&=(x_2-x_1)^2+(x_2-x_1)^2((x_2+x_1) + a)^2\\
&=(x_2-x_1)^2(1+((x_2+x_1) + a)^2)\\
\end{array}
$

If
$x_2-x_1 = d$,
$L^2
=d^2(1+((2x_1+d) + a)^2)
$.

The equation of the chord is

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}
&=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\\
&=\dfrac{(x_2^2+ax_2+b)-(x_1^2+ax_1+b)}{x_2-x_1}\\
&=\dfrac{x_2^2-x_1^2+a(x_2-x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\\
&=x_2+x_1+a\\
&=u\\
\end{array}
$

where
$u =  x_2+x_1+a$,

or

$\begin{array}\\
y
&=y_1+(x-x_1)u\\
&=ux+x_1^2+ax_1+b-ux_1\\
&=ux+x_1^2+ax_1+b-(x_2+x_1+a)x_1\\
&=ux+b-x_2x_1\\
\end{array}
$

The area under the chord is

$\begin{array}\\
A_c
&=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} (ux+y_1-ux_1)dx\\
&=(\dfrac{ux^2}{2}+y_1x-ux_1x)|_{x_1}^{x_2}\\
&=\dfrac{u(x_2^2-x_1^2)}{2}+y_1(x_2-x_1)-ux_1(x_2-x_1)\\
&=(x_2-x_1)(\dfrac{u(x_2+x_1)}{2}-ux_1+y_1)\\
&=(x_2-x_1)(\dfrac{u(x_2-x_1)}{2}+y_1)\\
&=(x_2-x_1)(\dfrac{(x_2+x_1+a)(x_2-x_1)}{2}+y_1)\\
&=(x_2-x_1)(\dfrac{x_2^2-x_1^2+a(x_2-x_1)}{2}+x_1^2+ax_1+b)\\
&=(x_2-x_1)(\dfrac{x_2^2+x_1^2+a(x_2+x_1)}{2}+b)\\
\end{array}
$

The area under the parabola is

$\begin{array}\\
A_p
&=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} (x^2+ax+b)dx\\
&=(\dfrac{x^3}{3}+a\dfrac{x^2}{2}+bx)|_{x_1}^{x_2}\\
&=\dfrac{x_2^3-x_1^3}{3}+a\dfrac{x_2^2-x_1^2}{2}+b(x_2-x_1))\\
&=(x_2-x_1)\left(\dfrac{x_2^2+x_2x_1+x_1^2}{3}+a\dfrac{x_2+x_1}{2}+b\right)\\
\end{array}
$

The difference is,
noting that the
$a$ and $b$ terms cancel out,

$\begin{array}\\
A_{cp}
&=A_c-A_p\\
&=(x_2-x_1)\left(\dfrac{x_2^2+x_1^2}{2}-\dfrac{x_2^2+x_2x_1+x_1^2}{3}\right)\\
&=(x_2-x_1)\left(\dfrac{x_2^2+x_1^2-2x_2x_1}{6}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{(x_2-x_1)^3}{6}\\
\end{array}
$

I find this very surprising.

This is the kind of result that,
if it is really true,
probably has a much simpler proof.

Now to incorporate
the length restriction.

We have
$L^2
=(x_2-x_1)^2(1+((x_2+x_1) + a)^2)
$.

So we want to minimize
$(x_2-x_1)^3$
subject to
$L^2
=(x_2-x_1)^2(1+((x_2+x_1) + a)^2)
$.

The following discussion
is taken from
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

The Lagrangian is
$h(x_1, x_2, \lambda)
=(x_2-x_1)^3
-\lambda((x_2-x_1)^2(1+((x_2+x_1) + a)^2)-L^2)
$
or,
using simplified variables
($x_1 \to x, x_2 \to y, \lambda \to z$),
$h(x, y, z)
=(y-x)^3
-z((y-x)^2(1+((y+x) + a)^2)-L^2)
=f(x, y)
-zg(x, y)
$.

So we want to solve

$g(x, y) = 0,
\nabla_{x, y}f(x, y)
=z\nabla_{x, y}g(x, y)
$
where
$\nabla_{x, y}f(x, y)
=\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)
$.

I think this is close
to the end,
but it's late and I'm tired.

So,
once again,
I am leaving an incomplete answer
in the hope that
someone else can
finish it.

Comment: Not entirely surprising. The area bounded by a parabola and a chord is equal to two-thirds the area of the bounding paralellogram.

Answer (score 0):

The parabola has the same shape as $y=x^2$. The chord length of $1$ parallel to the $x$-axis connects points $\big(\pm\frac 12, \frac14\big)$. By symmetry this chord gives the largest area.

See Desmos illustration [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qq3drk7ury).
For simplicity, in the illustration, the chord is fixed as the segment between $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$, and the parabola rotates.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The area bounded by the parabola and the chord is given by 
$$2\int_0^{\frac 12}\frac 14-x^2 \;\;dx=\frac 16$$